# Change variable on resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, onresize

I'm trying to make the `containerHeight` variable change depending on the width of the browser. This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to proceed even after reading the docs. Can someone help me out?

```
var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
window.onresize = containerHeight;
$('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "px" to the end. Or 'em', whatever you're using

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    var containerHeight = $('#project-container').outerHeight();
    $('#project-wrapper.activated').css('max-height', containerHeight + 'px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add an event listener for the window resize event:

```
window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
```

and then change that variable in the callback:

```
function onWindowResize() { }
```